Element is present in DOM, but cannot be interacted with
I'm practicing with this website
https://automationtesting.co.uk/ and need for my program to press a toggle button (which shows/hides the sidebar content) in case I cannot interact with whatever I'm trying to do there (clicking a hyperlink in my case).
The problem is that whenever the sidebar is not visible, all the elements inside it will still be present in my DOM. See for yourself by searching for h2 selector with the sidebar being closed. It will locate the "Menu" label even though you cannot see it on the page. The same goes for every single element in there.
And so I cannot check whether they're displayed, enabled, or clickable - because such condition checks, for some reason, will always return true, hence they're useless. And at the same time I cannot just click() on anything inside the sidebar while it's closed.
So what can the solution be?
I tried:

Regular condition checks: isDisplayed(); isEnabled().
Wrapping the code in a try-catch blocks and attempting to check whether the element meets a certain condition via explicit waits.


check for the inactive class in div first;  

@tik27 that should solve it, thank you so much, didn't think of that for some reason

Presence means the element is in the DOM but not that it's visible. Visibility is a different check. You can in fact use .isDisplayed() to test if the element is visible/displayed or not. See the code sample below that checks the "BUTTONS" link, clicks the left nav toggle, and then checks the "BUTTONS" link again. It prints true then false just as you would expect. Right below that is code that uses WebDriverWait to wait for visible/invisible after toggling. All this code works as expected.
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

...

String url = "https://automationtesting.co.uk/";

driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get(url);

By buttonsLocator = By.xpath("//a[text()='Buttons']");
WebElement buttons = driver.findElement(buttonsLocator);
System.out.println(buttons.isDisplayed()); // true
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.toggle")).click();
System.out.println(buttons.isDisplayed()); // false

// using WebDriverWait to wait for visible/invisible
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.toggle")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(buttonsLocator));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.toggle")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(buttonsLocator));

